How can I troubleshoot a failed electrical circuit?
My electric shower and my drainage pump (wet room) are connected to a separate fuse box to the rest of the property.
Neither are working. I have checked the fuse box and nothing has tripped. Both were working fine, then the pump stopped working and now the shower has.

Is there power at the fuse box?  Most of them have another breaker/fuse in the main panel, which might have tripped first.

If the fuses are still good, then it is likely that a wire feeding your pump and shower has been broken or a connection is poor or melted off.
You can get a voltmeter to test the electrical connections from the main power box to the pump and shower, trying to pin down where the voltage stops reading on the meter. Between where the voltage is present and where it is not is the break.
Note that if you're a renter, your landlord may have to arrange for an electrician to find the problem. Also, if you're not renting but you don't have the DIY skills to handle high-voltage electricity safely, you may need an electrician.

"high" voltage?  Isn't this just 120?

@WestCoastProjects I think it's 240 (or at least 230), because of the electric shower, which I believe is a European or British thing, But I do consider 120 high voltage, myself, it's got a lot more zap than touch-without-thinking flashlight batteries or USB, and needs more care.

ah ok 240.. yea that packs a punch. tbh 120 does not scare me as long as you don't get a sustained hit.

The "separate" fuse box should be fed from a circuit breaker or fuse in your main panel/fuse box. Check that it hasn't tripped or blown, or been accidentally turned off.


How can I troubleshoot a failed electrical circuit?


understand the wiring going back to the source
keep tracing back till you find the problem

